# Virtualization architecture on mainframe (z/Architecture)

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualization, mainframe

I have with interest studied the hardware virtualization extensions added by Intel and AMD to the x86 architecture (known as VMX and SVM, respectively). While this is still a relatively recent addition to x86 CPU's my understanding is that the mainframe architecture made extensive use of virtualization since the 70's-80's for instance in the form of the venerable z/VM operating system. Even nested virtualization has been used.

My question is, is there a public documentation of the hardware facilities provided by the z/Architecture used by the z/VM operating system to implement this virtualization? I.e. the control registers and data structures that the hardware implements to allows the hypervisor to simulate the guest state and trap necessary instructions? Another thing I am curious about is if the z/Architecture supports second-level address translation (which was added later to VMX and SVM).

Comment: I remember attending a 'Linux under VM' course and were were told that at one stage during installation, the guest OS would be very slow. This was because the mainframe was running VM, and we had each created our own VM's in which we then ran VM (OK so far?). Under this VM we created a Linux guest and this would become slow because there was no hardware support for running a guest OS (linux) under a guest OS under a guest OS, and the last layer of emulation was in software. Once we booted our Linux VM under native VM, all was OK..

Comment: If I recall correctly, The original VM was later implemented in firmware as PR/SM (Prism) and is the z-series mainframe's standard hypervisor for LPAR (Logical PARtitions - or VM's) support.

Comment: Going back to my first comment, we might actually have been running Linux under VM under VM under PR/SM when it got slow. Linux under VM under PR/SM was OK with full hardware emulation.

Comment: You might want the Principles of Operation, the latest PDF of which is IBM document SA22-7832-10.

Comment: Hi thanks I did browse through PoO  buy couldn't find a reference to any virtualization  facility apart from of course standard virtual memory.

Comment: @Steve: Interesting - but makes sense there must be some limit to how far you can go. Intel also has support for nested virtualization but I believe it only goes one extra layer deep (by allowing the hypervisor to avoid some traps generated by the hypervisor below it).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just to get it out of the way, System/370 and all its descendants support virtualization as is (they satisfy [virtualization requirements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Popek_and_Goldberg_virtualization_requirements)). In that sense, no special hardware support has ever been needed, as opposed to Intel architecture.

The performance improvements for VM guests on System/370, XA, ESA etc. all the way through z/Architecture have been traditionally implemented using `DIAG` (diagnose) instruction as well as microcode (now millicode) assist. In modern terms, it is more of paravirtualization. The facilities are documented, you can start [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSB27U_6.3.0/com.ibm.zvm.v630.hcpb4/toc.htm) for instance.

*Update* - after reading extensive comments, a few notes and clarifications.

1. S/370 and its descendants never needed specialized hardware virtualization support to correctly run guest operating systems - not because the virtualization was part of the initial design and requirements - it wasn't, but because the architecture was properly designed to support secure multiuser environment. Popek and Goldberg's virtualization requirements are actually very weak - in essence, that only privileged instructions can affect system configuration. This requirement was part of even S/370's predecessor, System/360, well before first virtualized systems appeared.
2. Performance imporvements of VM guests proceeded along two lines.

   - First, paravirtualization approach - essentially developing well-architected API for guest-hypervisor communication. It's been used not only for performance, but for a wide variety of other services such as inter-VM communication. The API is documented in the manual referred to above.
   - Second, microcode extensions (VM microcode assist) that performed some performance sensitive hypervisor logic at microcode level, essentially hardware level. That is not paravirtualization, it is hardware virtualization support proper. But in early 370 machines this support was not architected, meaning it was model-dependent and subject to change. With 370/XA, IBM introduced a proper architectural way to support high-performance virtualization, the Start Interpretive Execution (`SIE`) instruction. This instruction is not documented in Principles of Operation, but rather in a separate publication, [IBM System/370 XA Interpretive Execution](http://bitsavers.trailing-edge.com/pdf/ibm/370/princOps/SA22-7095-0_370-XA_Interpretive_Execution_Jan84.pdf). (This document is referenced multiple times in Principles of Operation. The link refers to the first version of the document, you can download version 2 [here](http://www.computinghistory.org.uk/det/9065/IBM-System-370-Extended-Architecture-Interpretive-Execution/). I am not sure if that publication was ever updated - probably this is the latest version.) Additionally, I/O subsystem provided VM assist too.

I failed to mention the `SIE` instruction and the manual that documented it in my original answer, which is a crucial part of the story. I am grateful to the author of the question and the extensive comments that proded me to check my memory and figure out that I skipped an important bit of technical background. [This presentation](http://www.vm.ibm.com/devpages/bitner/presentations/virtualb.pdf) provides an excellent overview of z/VM core facilities that covers additional aspects including memory management, I/O, networking etc.

Comment: Yuri, thanks - though I am not sure why you write "in that sense, no special hardware support has ever been needed, as opposed to Intel architecture". I guess another way to put it would be to say that the architecture just had the hardware support to begin with. Intel's problem was that they didn't fullfil the virtualization requirements to begin with, then had to retrofit them. But I am wondering why Intel's "retrofrit" seems to be that more complex and "explicit" about being for virtualization than IBM's. I am thinking, Intel could have retrofitted virtualization...

Comment: ... more simply by just adding a few control register bits that would make the CPU trap the few sensitive instructions that weren't priviledged, so that the virtualization requirements were fulfilled and trap-and-emulate would be an option.  It would just be a few control register bits and a few pages of documentation to describe that. Instead we have a very complex addition with special structures for state and all kinds of controls. I guess these have been added to provide a higher level of performance than what the basic trip-and-emulate scheme could offer. But then the...

Comment: ... obvious next question is, how can the mainframe virtualization be fast without having these more sophisticated facilities. And there it seems the answer might lie in the second part of your response, namely that the z/Architecture, while fullfilling the virtualization requirements, isn't solely based on classic virtualization but instead of para-virtualizatoin. The guest cooperates heavily with the hypervisor through assists and there are lot of priviledged things including surrounding memory management...

Comment: ... that happens almost like function calls from guest to hypervisor. If this understanding is correct, then I guess the answer to the original question is that the mainframe does not have or require hardware virtualization facilities to anywhere near the same extent (including second-level address translation etc.) as Intel since the architecture relies more heavily on para-virtualization (probably due to IBM being the main hardware ahd operating system developer, at least historically)

Comment: @Morty - thanks for your comments. Please see update, especially the elaboration on VM assist and `SIE` instruction. As you see, the mainframe virtualization proceeded along both lines - paravirtualization and hardware support.

Comment: Thanks for your very elaborate answer. I am now reading the links and presentations. Seems the SIE is really the heart of the matter and is what corresponds most closely to the Intel VT-x/VMX architecture - the SIE instruction is almost directly comparable to the Intel VMLAUNCH instruction that launches the virtualized environment based on the state specified in the VMCS structure. It is somewhat curious it is called an "interpreted" environment (in the SIE name) since it is presumably run on the real hardware at full speed, and not interpreted as such.

Answer (score 1):

The SIE instruction is how virtualization software accesses the z/Architecture Interpretive Execution Facility (IEF).  The exact details of the interface have not been published since the early 1990s.

This is a hardware-based capability.  IEF provides two levels of virtualization.  The first level is used by firmware (via the SIE instruction) to create **partitions**.  In each partition you can run an operating system.  One of those operating systems is z/VM.  It uses the SIE instruction (running within the context of the first level SIE instruction) to run **virtual machines**.  You can run any z/Architecture operating system in a virtual machine, including z/VM itself.

The SIE instruction takes as input the description of a virtual server (partition or virtual machine).  The hardware then runs the virtual server's instruction stream, stopping only when it needs help from whatever issued the SIE instruction, whether it be the partition hypervisor or the z/VM hypervisor.

Comment: Hi Alan thanks for adding this as well! I think it is super interesting to study the development of these advanced facilities through the various architecture. One further question, why is the SIE documentation not published? Is it not possible for other companies to write hypervisor software (or is it only avail on request)? Actually a second question: Why was it called "interpretive" environment because presumably the instructions are executed on the hardware! Is it because the instruction interprets a data structure that encodes a machine state, and then proceeds with execution from there?

Comment: Hi, Morty.  "Interpretive" is really a hypervisor perspective, rather than a machine implementation.  "It will run until it can't, and then it's your problem to deal with" or the hardware provides information established by the hypervisor instead of taken from the hardware.  (Example: Delta to be added to hardware clock when virtual server asks what time it is.)

Comment: As to why it isn't published?  Because it's part of the licensed specification.  If someone wants to create their own OS for IBM Z or build their own hardware, they would license the complete architecture spec from IBM.  Applications, on the other hand, need only the information in the published specification.

Perhaps not a very emotionally satisfying answer, but there are some people in this world who would like to take all of IBM's 50 years of work on the mainframe and use it for free to make money for themselves *at the expense of IBM*.